# Can I reproduce data using "random()" in different operating systems?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, random

I'm writing a SQL script (PostgreSQL) that inserts 50k+ rows of pseudo random data into several tables using the `random()` function, and I wanted to know if this function is stable between operating systems. I generate many columns of data, but the gist of the script looks like:

```
select setseed(0.5); -- make it reproducible

select g.id, floor(random() * 1000000)::int as code
from generate_series(1, 5) g(id)
```

Result:

```
id    code
--  ------
 1  249910
 2  520017
 3  461175
 4  227737
 5  184899
```

Different members of the team may use Windows and MacOS during development, and the integration servers use Linux. Until PostgreSQL 11 the docs included the somewhat cryptic [to me] message:

> The characteristics of the values returned by random() depend on the system implementation. It is not suitable for cryptographic applications; see pgcrypto module for an alternative.

So my question is, is the implementation of `random()` *identical* everywhere, or will this script generate the **different** data in different operating systems?

Comment: what do you mean by 'will this script generate the different data' knowing that randow() always returns different data by definition ? What kind of 'difference' could you expect between Windows, MacOS, Linux ?

Comment: @EdouardH. not necessarily. You can use `setseed()` to reproduce 'random' results. See [Math](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-math.html): Table 9.6. Random Functions.

Comment: According to this commit [6645ad6bdd](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=6645ad6bdd81e7d5a764e0d94ef52fae053a9e13) it should be uniform. That looks to be around version 11.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thank you very much. It reads "Also, we should now have uniform behavior of random() across platforms, which is worth something." -- I think this is actually quite valuable. I wish the documentation was clearer.